# How to evaluate the string in ruby if the string contains ruby command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

In my case,

I was storing the sql query in my database as text.
I am showing you one record which is present in my database

Query.all

```
:id  => 1, :sql => "select * from user where id = #{params[:id]}"

str = Query.first
```

Now 'str' has value "select * from user where id = #{params[:id]}"

Here, I want to parsed the string like
If my params[:id] is 1 then

"select * from user where id = 1"

I used eval(str). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL string stored in the database should use substitution parameters instead of Ruby code. The SQL string should be stored in the format shown below:

```
   str = "\"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND type = ? \", 
              params[:id], params[:type]"
```

Now you can substitute the value for the parameters using the class method `sanitize_sql_array` and eval.

```
sql = eval("User.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [#{str}])")
users = User.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Comment: sanitize_sql_array - how can I call this protected method?

Comment: You could call it from a method inside your Query class as that is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` so the method will be visible. Alternatively, it can be called using `send` so your `eval` would be something like `eval("Query.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [#{str}])")`

Answer (score 4):

`eval` would do what you describe in this instance. However this is a **very bad idea** as it is susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). e.g. consider what would happen if `params[:id]` was equal to "1; delete * from queries".

If you need a way to store arbitrary queries in your database you would be better to store the parameterised version of the query:

```
select * from user where id = ?
```

and `eval` the parameters separately.